# Azure Devops: agentless deployment to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I´m preparing a release to deploy a web app to a Azure App Service and seems that this task is not available as part of an agentless job. Thinking a bit about it, I wonder why. I mean: In my understanding, deploy to Azure is essentially take the artifact (assuming that is already stored in Azure devops) and deploy in the resource provided in the service connection through the actions performed by the Deployment task.

I would say that this process does not (necessarily) requires an agent out of the Azure Devops environment to be done (at the end, we are moving things between PaaS) but seems that we are enforced to use it.

1. Is my thought correct or I'm missunderstanding anything?
2. Any way to perform this kind of deployment without agents? (my Azure App Service has a private endpoint, so only self-hosted agents are able to reach it and I would like to avoid create them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Azure DevOps Pipeline needs an Agent to run it (the workload must run somewhere, right?). If you use private endpoints and you want to **PUSH** your deployment to Azure App Services, you will have to create a self-hosted Agent that is connected to the App Service VNET. There is no way around it.

However, Azure App Service enables continuous deployment from Azure Repos repositories by **pulling** the sources (See [Continuous deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github). This will probably also work with private endpoints (not tested it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not doubt that an agent is necessary to run the Pipeline, I doubt that the deployment to a Azure App Service requires an agent (others tasks which interact with Azure, like "Publish to Azure Service Bus" or "Invoke Azure functions" work in agentless jobs)

Comment: Okay, I got your point now. But anyway, even if the Task would be available for agentless, you won't be able to reach your App Service cause you are using private endpoints...

Comment: That's correct. In case of private endpoint seems that there is no way without agent. For public endpoints maybe would be a good idea to create an agentless version...